# How to merge two differently ordered arrays by columns

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I am trying to `cbind` two differently ordered named arrays into a dataframe.

```
x = c("a" = 1, "z" = 10)
y = c("z" = 10, "a" = 1)

# Expected output:
#   x  y
# a 1  1
# z 10 10
```

I've tried the following and all ignored the arrays' names:

```
# Unexpected outputs: 
cbind(x,y)
merge(as.data.frame(x),as.data.frame(y))
library(dplyr); bind_cols(as.data.frame(x),as.data.frame(y))
```

In principle, I know that I could transform the arrays into `dataframe` and then bind by row names, or I could match the names and index the arrays during binding.

I was wondering if there is a more straight forward way for such a straight forward task.

Comment: Order by the names `cbind(x, y = y[order(names(y))])`.  Of course, this assumes that `x` is already ordered, which may or may not be true.

Comment: @RichardScriven Agree, but this also assumes that all the elements are present in the two arrays and just differently ordered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with

```
x <- c("a" = 1, "z" = 10)
y <- c("z" = 10, "a" = 1)

cbind(x, "y"=y[names(x)])

>   x  y
>a  1  1
>z 10 10
```

May not be optimal but maybe it is enough for your purposes...

Comment: Much much better than the `as.data.frame` ideas that I came up with. Thanks Martin!